# Help Me For Implementing MySQL tuner suggesstions

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

Mine is Digitalocean with 1vCPU, 1GB -25GB SSD Ubuntu server with nginx, MariaDB, phpmyadmin and running a wordpress blog. Mysql is taking too much cpu and on running running MySqlTuner, I got these suggestions:

```
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_size (> 16M)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

the ouput of ulimit -a:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 3788
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 3788
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The full MySqlTuner report is as follows:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.8.1 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.pl/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials from Debian maintenance account.
[!!] failed to execute: SHOW REPLICA STATUS\G
[!!] FAIL Execute SQL / return code: 256
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.3.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log doesn't exist

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 267.8M (Tables: 54)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 416.0K (Tables: 20)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1d 12h 39m 35s (5M q [39.556 qps], 41K conn, TX: 196G, RX: 657M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 96% / 4%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 981.3M
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 3.2G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 432.0M global + 18.9M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 564.4M (57.51% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 3.2G (335.01% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (8/5M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 4% (7/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (1/41165)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 33.8% (2M cached / 7M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 13820
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 1% (9K temp sorts / 532K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 77% (65K on disk / 84K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (7 created / 41K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 99% (2M hits / 2M requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache(400) is upper than number of tables(235)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (189/32K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (2M immediate / 2M locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 1 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.3.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 28.5% (38M used / 134M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/46.4M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (230M cached / 12K reads)
[OK] Write Key buffer hit rate: 99.5% (744K cached / 740K writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/416.0K
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (75 %): 48.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[!!] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 83.72% (1661 hits/ 1984 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 41.67% (5 hits/ 12 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 7 writes)

-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/0B
[!!] Aria pagecache hit rate: 87.4% (515K cached / 65K reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: OFF
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: OFF
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
    Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys for MySQL
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/FromDual/mariadb-sys for MariaDB
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: https://bit.ly/2TcGgtU
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_size (> 16M)
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

htop

[image]

What do I need to adjust in order to increase the performance of my MySQL instance and reduce cpu usgae?

Comment: increases the amount of ram so you aren't swapping.  With 40 queries per second, each query needs to finish in < 1/40s because you have a single CPU. Set your long_query_time to this. Fix all of these slow queries. CPU also needs to do other web things. Or, you could provide an amount of resources that is more substantial and matches your workload.

Comment: You mean i need to upgrade my existing droplet. Does Swapping is not good? I don't have idea. I'm new to this.

Comment: yes, start by doubling CPU and RAM.

Comment: You have a tiny database in a tiny machine.  (Don't increase the hardware -- yet.)  High CPU means lack of proper indexes and/or poorly formulated queries.  Let's see a slow query, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Also, use InnoDB, not MyISAM.

Comment: Swapping keeps you from dying.  Better to swap and be a few seconds slow than strangling to death with Out Of Memory.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thank You In Advance. Below are links for all additional informtion you asked 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; = https://pastebin.com/vNsA0ABP
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; = https://pastebin.com/XWP2y0VG
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; = https://pastebin.com/LBpGA3b6
E) STATUS; = https://pastebin.com/WPuddXdF
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;  = https://pastebin.com/4Aw4V0Z6
 iostat -xm 5 3 = https://pastebin.com/nanwzbUZ
 cpu detail = https://pastebin.com/5vGmAfTA

Comment: @RickJames Is it possible to convert existing MyISAM to InnoDB or should have to do everything from start.

Comment: @RickJames Where i run these command ` SHOW CREATE TABLE` on root showing SHOW Command Not Found and on mysql showing "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Comment: @VishalGupta From your MySQL Command Prompt, you can run the SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;   Do you use cpanel to manage your Digital Ocean installation?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thank you for telling me. Have you checked above url's? Any suggestions?

Comment: @VishalGupta - `ALTER TABLE` can convert.  But read my other notes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: @VishalGupta Will try to have some suggestions in Answer to you within 24 hours.  Thanks for posting the requested data.

Comment: wprd_postmeta will probably benefit from installing https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Comment: Is it WordPress?

Comment: @RickJames Yes it is wordpress.

Comment: @VishalGupta - This is likely to help with performance: https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Answer (score 1):

**Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:**

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.3.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
- 0.98 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 2d 17:09:21
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) MyISAM.

**The More Important Issues:**

Moving to MyISAM is strongly encouraged.

These days, 1GB is a tiny RAM size.  Still, it should be possible to run in 1GB.  Some of the comments below will help with running in 1GB.

If you continue not to use InnoDB, decrease `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 16M.

Lower `max_connections` to 10.

**Details and other observations:**

[Conversion from MyISAM to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb)

`( Key_blocks_used * 1024 / key_buffer_size ) = 13,886 * 1024 / 128M = 10.6%` -- Percent of key_buffer used. High-water-mark.
-- Lower key_buffer_size (now 134217728) to avoid unnecessary memory usage.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 128M` -- InnoDB Data + Index cache
-- 128M (an old default) is woefully small.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 128M / 1053340729.344 = 12.7%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool
-- Set to about 70% of available RAM. (To low is less efficient; too high risks swapping.)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free * 16384 / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 7,735 * 16384 / 128M = 94.4%` -- buffer pool free
-- buffer_pool_size is bigger than working set; could decrease it

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- When flushing, use this many IOPs.
-- Reads could be slugghish or spiky.

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 7,735 / 8192 = 94.4%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 134217728) is bigger than necessary?

`( (Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_pages_read) / ((Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_pages_read) + (Key_writes + Key_reads)) ) = (151 + 322) / ((151 + 322) + (1375700 + 13062)) = 0.03%` -- % InnoDB I/O (vs MyISAM)
-- InnoDB is the preferred Engine these days.

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_reads / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests ) = 323 / 1984 = 16.3%` -- Read requests that had to hit disk
-- Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 134217728) if you have enough RAM.

`( Innodb_pages_read / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests ) = 322 / 1984 = 16.2%` -- Read requests that had to hit disk
-- Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 134217728) if you have enough RAM.

`( Innodb_pages_written / Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests ) = 151 / 928 = 16.3%` -- Write requests that had to hit disk
-- Check innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 134217728)

`( Innodb_dblwr_pages_written/Innodb_pages_written ) = 20/151 = 13.2%` -- Seems like these values should be equal?

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster. 0 is OK for Galera.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( min( tmp_table_size, max_heap_table_size ) ) = (min( 16M, 16M )) / 1053340729.344 = 1.6%` -- Percent of RAM to allocate when needing MEMORY table (per table), or temp table inside a SELECT (per temp table per some SELECTs). Too high may lead to swapping.
-- Decrease tmp_table_size (now 16777216) and max_heap_table_size (now 16777216) to, say, 1% of ram.

`( 176000 * max_connections ) = (176000 * 151) / 1053340729.344 = 2.5%` -- Estimate of ram usage due to the size of max_connections.
-- max_connections (now 151) is somewhat high

`( myisam_sort_buffer_size ) = 134,216,704 / 1053340729.344 = 12.7%` -- Used for ALTER, CREATE INDEX, OPTIMIZE, LOAD DATA; set when you need it. Also for MyISAM's REPAIR TABLE.
-- Decrease myisam_sort_buffer_size (now 134216704) to keep from blowing out RAM.

`( innodb_ft_result_cache_limit ) = 2,000,000,000 / 1053340729.344 = 189.9%` -- Byte limit on FULLTEXT resultset. (Possibly not preallocated, but grows?)
-- Lower the setting.

`( (Com_show_create_table + Com_show_fields) / Questions ) = (0 + 114700) / 9647512 = 1.2%` -- Naughty framework -- spending a lot of effort rediscovering the schema.
-- Complain to the 3rd party vendor.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Key_blocks_used * 1024 / key_buffer_size ) = 13,886 * 1024 / 128M = 10.6%` -- Percent of key_buffer used . High-water-mark.
-- Lower key_buffer_size (now 134217728) to avoid unnecessary memory usage.

`( (Key_writes + Key_reads) / ((Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_pages_read) + (Key_writes + Key_reads)) ) = (1375700 + 13062) / ((151 + 322) + (1375700 + 13062)) = 100.0%` -- % MyISAM I/O (vs InnoDB)
-- InnoDB is the preferred Engine these days.

`( Key_writes / Key_write_requests ) = 1,375,700 / 1381646 = 99.6%` -- key_buffer effectiveness for writes
-- If you have enough RAM, it would be worthwhile to increase key_buffer_size (now 134217728).

`( (query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache / query_alloc_block_size ) = (16M - 6071944) / 2482 / 16384 = 0.263` -- query_alloc_block_size vs formula
-- Adjust query_alloc_block_size (now 16384)

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 121,975 / 156296 = 78.0%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Maybe increase tmp_table_size (now 16777216) and max_heap_table_size (now 16777216); improve indexes; avoid blobs, etc.

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( innodb_autoinc_lock_mode ) = 1` -- Galera: desires 2 -- 2 = "interleaved"; 1 = "consecutive" is typical; 0 = "traditional".
-- Galera desires 2; 2 requires BINLOG_FORMAT=ROW or MIXED

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Subquery_cache_hit / ( Subquery_cache_hit + Subquery_cache_miss ) ) = 23,792 / ( 23792 + 61652 ) = 27.8%` -- Subquery cache hit rate

`( back_log ) = 80` -- (Autosized as of 5.6.6; based on max_connections)
-- Raising to min(150, max_connections (now 151)) may help when doing lots of connections.

`( Max_used_connections / max_connections ) = 7 / 151 = 4.6%` -- Peak % of connections
-- Since several memory factors can expand based on max_connections (now 151), it is good not to have that setting too high.

`( thread_cache_size / Max_used_connections ) = 151 / 7 = 2157.1%`
-- There is no advantage in having the thread cache bigger than your likely number of connections. Wasting space is the disadvantage.

**Abnormally small:**

```
( Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written ) / Uptime = 0.00202
Acl_users = 3
Handler_commit = 0.031 /HR
Handler_commit/Questions = 0.00%
Handler_read_first = 1.5 /HR
Handler_read_rnd_next / Handler_read_rnd = 0.312
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data = 32 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data = 457
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed / max(Questions, Queries) = 1.6e-5
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc = 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc * 16384 / innodb_buffer_pool_size = 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests = 30 /HR
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests / (Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests + Innodb_buffer_pool_reads ) = 86.0%
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests = 14 /HR
Innodb_data_fsyncs = 0.26 /HR
Innodb_data_read = 23 /sec
Innodb_data_reads = 5.5 /HR
Innodb_data_writes = 2.5 /HR
Innodb_data_writes - Innodb_log_writes - Innodb_dblwr_writes = 2.4 /HR
Innodb_data_written = 12 /sec
Innodb_log_write_requests = 0.18 /HR
Innodb_num_open_files = 28
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs = 0.15 /HR
Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group = 0.0MB
Innodb_pages_created = 2.1 /HR
Innodb_pages_read = 4.9 /HR
Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written = 7.3 /HR
Innodb_pages_written = 2.3 /HR
Innodb_rows_deleted + Innodb_rows_inserted = 0
Innodb_rows_inserted = 0
Innodb_rows_read = 0
Innodb_rows_updated = 0
Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads = 0
eq_range_index_dive_limit = 0
innodb_spin_wait_delay = 4
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Handler_discover = 0.8 /HR
Handler_read_next / Handler_read_key = 317
Handler_read_rnd = 17988 /sec
Key_blocks_warm = 7,622
Memory_used = 28.3%
Sort_rows = 17988 /sec
Tc_log_page_size = 4,096
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
Innodb_have_snappy = ON
aria_recover_options = BACKUP,QUICK
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
log_slow_admin_statements = ON
myisam_stats_method = NULLS_UNEQUAL
old_alter_table = DEFAULT
```

Comment: Thank You for providing me such a great suggestion but literally i'm confused should i implement these suggestion after converting to innobd?

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS
Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section to improve performance

```
max_connections=32  # from 151 for your 1G server until addl RAM available
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 18,512
read-rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 5,621
net_buffer_length=64K  # from 16K to reduce sent packet count
```

Many more opportunities are available to improve performance.
View profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Observation:
Most Linux/Ubuntu systems use O_DIRECT for innodb_flush_method rather than fsync.

Comment: Do you really want to increase things in such a small "machine"?

Comment: Yes, two are up, two are down.  Considering the ups/downs likely to be a net gain in available RAM and performance should be improved by reducing interruptions.

Comment: implemented everything but there was no improvement that's why i leaved as it is there. By the way, I was new at this platform so don't know about closing threads.